# How to limit the number of rows in a specific table with PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, limit

We are trying to limit the number of registrations on our SIP server in the simplest way possible. More specifically, we have decided to limit the number of entries in the `users` table. The server is running PostgreSQL as the DBMS.

Is it possible to limit the number of entries in a specific table? For example, we want to limit the number of rows to 100 and we do not want any more entries on that table unless some of the old ones are deleted.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but that's a pretty bad way of solving this problem. You'll have to create a trigger that acquires an `EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table then checks the `count()` on the table before allowing a commit or, if the insert would add too many rows, doing a `RAISE EXCEPTION` to abort the transaction.

Two triggers, actually; a `BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE` trigger that does the `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` and an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that checks the `COUNT` of the table and decides whether to raise an exception. A simple `BEFORE` trigger is insufficient, since it can't tell if an `INSERT` might add more than one row, so a multi-valued insert or `INSERT ... SELECT` might cause the limit to be exceeded.

Other sessions that want to update the table will have to wait until the transaction doing the `INSERT` finishes. If the app isn't designed for this it could easily cause deadlocks.

The app probably doesn't expect to get an error when it `INSERT`s into the sessions table so it might not deal with that gracefully. It's rather unlikely to give the user a neat "too many registrations" error.

I haven't written a sample trigger for this because I think it's an absolutely *terrible* idea to do this. If you want to set a limit on how many users can be registered in your SIP server, configure your SIP server appropriately. If there's no such config option, modify it to add one or use a different SIP server that *does* have one.

Comment: I wonder if a slightly different method might work in lieu of triggers, such as 100 entries in the table and each SIP "user" needs to claim an entry and subsequent attempts block or fail if they cannot get an entry. As you say Craig, I think a more appropriate solution is fixing the application.

Comment: @bma That'd work, but would be prone to race conditions that would be hard to solve without landing back at the same sort of single-threaded approach or more application changes. How do you pick *which* one to claim in the face of concurrent inserts and deletes? If Pg supported `LIMIT 1 SKIP LOCKED` or something you could do it, but at present there's nothing like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit late, but we had the same problem so I would like to share my solution.
I assume that `user` table have some parent key or some relation.
You can do it in transaction by locking the parent record and checking a count of total users that meet your condition. If it is less than `limit` then you can insert new user. If you try to do that in another transaction you will be locked until the first one finished, or you can use `SKIP LOCKED` to get an empty result and finish the transaction.

Code:

```sql
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM user_parent WHERE /* condition */ FOR UPDATE;
SELECT count(1) FROM "user" WHERE /* condition */;
// check count in your code
// if count <= limit; then continue; else ROLLBACK
// INSERT your users
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, google brought me over here :

```
CONSTRAINT nomore_than_x_rows
CHECK( table_id < 101 );
```

given that the id is of type serial

Comment: This tecnique would work only if users are never deleted, because, if you delete a user, the new ids will be higher than 100.